# Why does $\cosh (x+y)$ has a plus in its resultant contrary to $\cos (x+y)$

Tags: trigonometry

ie. $\cos (x+y)=\cos x \cos y- \sin x \sin y$ but $\cosh (x+y) = \cosh x \cosh y+ \sinh x \sinh y$

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the fact that $i^2=-1$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\cosh(x+y) & = \cos(i(x+y)) = \cos(ix)\cos(iy) - \sin(ix) \sin(iy)\\
& = \cosh(x)\cosh(y) + \sinh(x) \sinh(y) \,\,\,\,\,\, (\because \cos(i \theta) = \cosh(\theta); \sin(i \theta) = i\sinh(\theta))
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

One could say that it is because $\sinh(ix)=i\sin x$, and $\sinh(iy)=i\sin y$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: $\cosh{x}$ increases with increasing values of $x$, while $\cos{x}$ decreases between $0$ and $\pi$.